# Batch: How to show only errors in console output (ie redirect STDOUT to NUL and STDERR to CON)?

Tags: batch, cmd.exe, redirection, stdout, stderr

I'm trying to figure out how to show *only* errors on the console output (and suppress all other output) without redirecting to a file or using TEE, etc.  I'm trying to get this to work for single commands in addition to calls to functions (`CALL :FunctionName arg1 arg2`).

I feel like an idiot for not being able to figure this out, but I can't find any examples of this online that I can get to work and none of the combinations of redirections I've used have worked.

How do you redirect `STDOUT` to `>NUL` and at the same time redirect `STDERR` to `>CON`?  Is it just by using `>NUL`?

It seems like some error messages appear in the STDOUT stream (e.g. `SC query BadServiceName`) depending on how the console app was written.  Is that an accurate assessment?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### How can I redirect `STDOUT` to `NUL` and redirect `STDERR` to `CON`?

```
program 1>nul
```

will redirect stdout to nul. This does not redirect `stderr` output which **should** go to the console...

If `program` also writes errors to `stdout` then you are out of luck using simple redirections.

See [Command Redirection, Pipes - Windows CMD - SS64.com](https://ss64.com/nt/syntax-redirection.html)